# IntelliJ Java Generic type inference for map stream

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, java-stream

Imagine the following class:

```
public class Test {

    private static List<Model<?>> getModels() {
        return List.of(10).stream()
            .map(Test::getModel)
            .toList();
    }

    private static Model<?> getModel(int key) {
        return new Model<>(key);
    }

    public static void main(String... str) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!" + getModels());
    }

    public static class Model<T> {

        private T field;

        Model(T key) {
            field = key;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Model(" + field + ")";
        }

    }

}
```

I am curious why IntelliJ can not infer the type of stream after map stage, and shows an Error?

When I explicitly add the type in the map stage as bellow, it works fine.

```
public class Test {

    private static List<Model<?>> getModels() {
        return List.of(10).stream()
            .<Model<?>>map(Test::getModel)
            .toList();
    }

    private static Model<?> getModel(int key) {
        return new Model<>(key);
    }

    public static void main(String... str) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!" + getModels());
    }

    public static class Model<T> {

        private T field;

        Model(T key) {
            field = key;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Model(" + field + ")";
        }

    }

}
```

Why IntelliJ shows it as an error, but the compilation is done without any errors? when I hover over it, this error is being shown:

```
Required type: List<Model<?>>

Provided: List<? extends Model<?>>
```

[image]

Comment: You say that the compiler cannot infer the type of the stream resulting from `.map()` because why, exactly?  I guess you must be getting a compiler error, but how about presenting the exact error message?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Interesting request, It took me some time, it seams that it compiles without error, I added the screenshot from IntelliJ, seams like a bug for IntelliJ or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please add the code for `Model` so that people can reproduce this.

Comment: @tgdavies Added the class for `Model` as well.

Comment: In your example, `getModel` returns `Model<Integer>` and so `getModels` returns `List<Model<Integer>>` and IntelliJ is happy once those signatures are changed.

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry I do not understand could you elaborate more, why there is not compilation error or warning?

Comment: Maybe IntelliJ’s error reporting is based on ECJ (as I get the same compiler error in Eclipse)?

Answer (score 0):

The Intellij compiler is incorrectly infering a more general return type for the map method (`Stream<? extends Model<?>>` when it should be `Stream<Model<?>>`). The Java compiler will still accept the code as it's correct, but if the IDE warning is annoying then you can suppress it by simply providing an explicit type argument:

```
return List.of(10).stream()
        .<Model<?>>map(Test::getModel)
        .toList();
```

Comment: I think it's weirder than that.  The question seems to show that the IDE is getting the type of `map()` correct (`Stream<Model<?>>`) even without the explicit type argument, but nevertheless getting the type of `toList()` wrong in that case.  Also, the question already notes that adding an explicit type argument to the `map()` invocation resolves the issue.

Comment: If you split the stream expression to take everything up to but *not* including the call to toList(), and assign it to a variable, you can see that the IDE infers the variable type as `Stream<? extends Model<?>>`. Ergo, the call to toList is not the problem.

Comment: @jonhanson When I hover over `map`, output of the `map` stage is of the type `Stream<Model<?>>` IDE shows it in front of the `map` as well, clearly the problem is from the `map` stage and not `toList()`, otherwise adding the explicit type( as mentioned in the question) would not solve the problem. But it seems that the type that IDE shows to us is different from the type that it really uses for the output of the map stage or in other words the type that it shows to us is coming from different source than the type it uses behind the scene.

Comment: @Tashkhisi if you introduce the variable as I suggested, set the type to something like int, the IDE will flag it as an error. If you then let the IDE auto correct the error it will change the type to `Stream<? extends Model<?>>`. I think we're saying the same thing.